# Mongo + Docker not allowing overlay driver for replica set

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I'm running this docker-compose.yml on my mac over a fresh Docker for Mac environment.

[Gist here!](https://gist.github.com/brunoguerra/4c89d8e42b6146c957c39c1d27b56311)

`version: '2'
services:
  replica1:
    image: mongo:3.0
    container_name: mongo1
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./mongodata/replica1:/data/db
    command: mongod --smallfiles --replSet "mrmtx"
    networks:
      - mongo_cluster
  replica2:
    image: mongo:3.0
    container_name: mongo2
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./mongodata/replica2:/data/db
    command: mongod --smallfiles --replSet "mrmtx"
    networks:
      - mongo_cluster
  replica3:
    image: mongo:3.0
    container_name: mongo3
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./mongodata/replica3:/data/db
    command: mongod --smallfiles --replSet "mrmtx"
    networks:
      - mongo_cluster
networks:
  mongo_cluster:
    driver: overlay`

I'm getting this error:

**Cannot start service replica2: b'Could not attach to network mongo-rplset_mongo_cluster: rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = network mongo-rplset_mongo_cluster not manually attachable'**

Comment: I would think you are using a swarm cluster because you're trying to deploy an overlay network (over multiple nodes)? In docker swarm you should docker `docker stack deploy -f docker-compose.yml`

Comment: @4525448/lvthillo I tried it and it pass. I need just adjust now mongo ports. Thank you!